# Add code to existing module: remove duplicate values in row 2

Tags: excel, vba

I created an existing module that will import text file into my spreadsheet and that works fine.  What I would like to do to speed up my process is to automatically remove rows.  The imported data size can vary so I can't use a fixed range.

```
Sub Import_Data()
    Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If Ret <> False Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Input Cell", Type:=8))

        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        End With
End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to happen is to scan the new file that is imported.  If any duplicate values exist in column 2, remove duplicate rows.

Comment: use .RemoveDuplicates

Comment: How would I do that?  Everything I create is from combining examples I find and I couldn't find anything for this.

Comment: maybe take a look at the documentation page? You need code to identify the range and perform a RemoveDuplicates on the identified range. It is not clear which range your data lives in, so I can't write a code suggestion with your ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the range that the data lives in, then apply the `RemoveDuplicates` method.

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
```

Your range may be constructed by looking up the row number after the data has been imported with your previous code

```
Dim myrow As Long
    ' get the row number of the last row of data in column A
    myrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' remove rows with duplicates in the second column, column B, in
    ' the table that sits in A1 to Cx
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & myrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
```